# The formatting error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" seems straightforward, but

Tags: support

The message seems straightforward, but I think there must be a lot more to it. I cannot get this question to post. I have four sections of code. I made sure each is indented at least four spaces. Do they all need to have *only* four spaces per line, and no other indentation allowed? This does not seem to be the answer because I tried it and still got the error, but what else could it be?

[image]

Comment: That ending list of paths should probably be code-formatted itself - it's not normal text, but a computer output. Also, please [no thank-yous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: You mean the URLs? I'll try that. No thank yous?

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Added for spaces to each, hit control-K which added the code marks, and still get the error. (Not sure I get what's the matter with having simple manners, but I removed the "thank you" too).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with good manners, but it doesn't add anything of value to the subject. And we have votes for showing appreciation. You can thank users in comments, but those comments might get removed sooner or later. Still, no one will frown upon niceties, don't worry!

Comment: Code blocks shouldn't start and end with backtick, that is for inline `code`. Either use a code fence (three backticks on a single line, one emtpy line above the starting backtick) or indent by four spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have edited my example with Bobble's suggestions, but am still receiving the formatting error. I would think it would qualify as correct formatting, but clearly there is something I'm missing.

Comment: If you have a github account, copy the content to a gist and leave us a link so we can try for ourselves, instead of having a guess at what might be wrong

Comment: Here is a list of things at the end of my answer for you to try: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340875

Comment: @rene I think your example did the trick! I have to wait some more time to post it but the error message went away. Thanks much!

Comment: It would be nice if you could self post an answer explaining what exactly worked

Answer (score 1):

A comment above turned out to be the solution, a post from an older answer from rene: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340875

To summarize, the solution was to replace the opening backtick in the code section (pictured above in the screenshot) with three backticks followed by a newline, and then replacing the closing backtick with a newline followed by three backticks. Without the need to add four spaces to each line, this removed the error.